# Run release-it without specifying a Github URL?

Tags: github, release-it

Is it possible to run [release-it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/release-it) without specifying a Github URL?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - per https://git.io/release-it-git.

```
npx release-it --no-git
```